# Relay compiler adds undefined on windows but not on mac os

Tags: undefined, relay

i am working with a team on an app i am on windows and they are on mac and when we run relay compiler script i get this :

```html
readonly " $data"?: productsListPagination$data | undefined;
```

and they get this instead without the "undefined":

```html
readonly " $data"?: productsListPagination$data;
```